# Cannot load PHP class when running Symfony command

Tags: php, symfony, docker, rabbitmq, amqp

I would appreciate any help I can get with following issue.

I've set up Symfony Messenger to use AMQP and RabbitMQ. I can dispatch message and make use of AMQPConnection within my project.

But when I try to consume the message I get following:

```
    $   php bin/console messenger:consume-messages amqp

        Attempted to load class "AMQPConnection" from the global namespace.
        Did you forget a "use" statement for "PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPConnection"?
```

The console command calls a method within `AmqpFactory.php`

```
    public function createConnection(array $credentials): \AMQPConnection
    {
        return new \AMQPConnection($credentials);
    }
```

So when I run the project from the browser, everything works fine. I can use AMQPConnection and all. But when running from terminal, it cannot find the AMQPConnection class.

From within my composer.json I also have the amqplib installed

```
    "php-amqplib/php-amqplib": "^2.7",
```

I use Docker and the Dockerfile contains:

```
    FROM php:7-apache

    RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data &&\
        a2dissite 000-default &&\
        apt-get update &&\
        apt-get install -y \
            zlib1g-dev \
            libicu-dev \
            g++ \
            libfreetype6-dev \
            libssh-dev \
            libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
            libmcrypt-dev \
            librabbitmq-dev \
            libpng-dev &&\
        docker-php-ext-configure intl &&\
        docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ &&\
        docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd pdo_mysql intl opcache zip pcntl exif bcmath sockets &&\
        a2enmod rewrite

    RUN pecl install amqp \
        && docker-php-ext-enable amqp

    COPY docker/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

    WORKDIR /var/www/project
```

**UPDATE!**
I've printed the phpinfo() and when dispatching the message I have version 7.2.8 and when executing the terminal command I have 7.2.7. So terminal is not using the Docker instance of PHP when executing the command.

Comment: Did you forget a "use" statement for "PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPConnection"?

Comment: Missed to add that part. Updated question above. The console command uses this method: return new \AMQPConnection($credentials);. It works to create the message, but not to consume it. Difference is when consuming I use Symfony console command.

Comment: But do you have a use statement in your console command code ? Can you add the relevant code of the Command class ?

Comment: @JeroenI added the statement which uses the AMQPConnection. It's really strange, same method is used when creating the message and that works just fine. When working with the terminal and activate the command to actual consume, I get this error. The credentials passed to connect is also correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this, finally. I had no idea I had to go via Docker to run this command. This worked for me:

`docker exec -ti container_name sh -c "cd /var/www/project/ && php  bin/console messenger:consume-messages amqp"`

Answer (score 2):

When using Docker, Symfony commands needs to be executed inside needed container.

The problem come from trying to execute php from the local host:

```sh
$ php bin/console messenger:consume-messages amqp
```

whereas the local host does **not** have the necessary dependencies, `RabbitMQ` in this case.

Instead the command should be run using the right container:

```sh
$ docker exec -ti container_name sh -c "cd /var/www/project/ && php  bin/console messenger:consume-messages amqp"
```

`container_name` being the name of the container having the `RabbitMQ` dependencies.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense! Appreciate it..awarding bounty and +1

Answer (score 1):

You are missing package `librabbitmq4` in your Docker container. Add `RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get update && apt-get install php-amqp` to your Dockerfile and rebuild the image.